# how can i mantain a specific proportion while resizing a window?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game in Python with a fullscreen option button.

How can I allow window resize when not in fullscreen, keeping the window ratio the same?

Also, how can I set the ratio to avoid problems if someone puts fullscreen in a monitor with a different ratio from 16/9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The screen resolution depends on the hardware. Not every hardware supports every resolution. You have to write an application that can handle different display resolutions. e.g.: [Scale Everything On Pygame Display Surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341589/scale-everything-on-pygame-display-surface/64341784#64341784).

Comment: so if someone is playing the game on a 1000x1000 resolution it'll be always stretched and we can do nothing about it?

Comment: @AndreaRoncella Of course you can do something about it. As I mentioned *"You have to write an application that can handle different display resolutions."*. You have to draw your scene depending on the resolution. However, how to do this depends on your application. There is no general solution that works for all applications. Taking care of different screen resolutions is part of a frontend developer's job.